# Page redirection not working with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angularjs routing in my web app, and I have included the $locationProvider and the base tag in HTML head which is `<base href="/webapp/">` in order to remove the hash symbol in the URL, it works fine when I redirect using anchor tags e.g. `<a href="/webapp/home">Home</a>` but gives a 404 error when I redirect using javascript e.g. `window.location.href = '/webapp/home';`. Tried everything but so far nothing, any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please show us some code?

Comment: try to use $location.path('/webapp/home');

Comment: What's the webserver? If nginx, add some loction try_files. Check [angular html5mode with nginx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810142/ngix-config-for-angularjs-html5-mode-with-templates-and-assets)

Comment: sorry didn't see the comments but I am using apache server and already solved it using .htaccess file, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

**Try** : `<a href="#/webapp/home">Home</a>`

When you are using angular(JavaScript) routing; JavaScript routing start after `#` keyword in URL, other wise browser think this is the server side routing trigger; or page will get refresh.

**USE** : `<a href="#/webapp/home">Home</a>`

$locationProvider will remove the `#` after redirecting to the the view.

Comment: Tried it, but all it gives me is this URL in the URL bar http://localhost/webapp/#%2Fwebapp%2Fhome and doesn't go to the desired page

Comment: Figured it out, it was all in the .htaccess file, and no, you don't include the # in every URL, here is the .htaccess code I included: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.htm [QSA,L]`